# How to update phonegap to 3.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, npm

I'm trying to update my version of phonegap:

```
C:\Users\jhutber>phonegap -v
3.3.0-0.19.6

npm update -g phonegap 
//runs....

//even updating npm
npm update npm -g

C:\Users\jhutber>npm info phonegap version
3.3.0-0.19.6
```

So how can I update my machine to use phonegap 3.4.0?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: No errors, it 'updates' successfully to the current version I already have installed.

Answer (score 2):

$ sudo npm update -g cordova

its the command for update your Phonegap App...

in case you need more information visit:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Ye, other than I'm using phonegap, this is what I have done already. As you can see.

Comment: did you read the docs on the link? it's the official docs for Phonegap cheers!

Comment: YE! and they give the same commands as the ones I've listed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at doing similar, hit the same issues. In the end I removed phone gap using a variety of

```
npm uninstall -g phonegap
npm uninstall phonegap
npm un phonegap
npm rm phonegap
npm -g rm phonegap
```

one of them worked, all of them complained.

Then check phonegap was gone, and

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Seemed to work now at version 3.4.0-0.19.7

As an aside, I also drew a pentagram around my desk using the blood of a recently slaughtered goat, and I'm seriously starting to think that was the clincher..

Cheers
Ant